# Split a file into four parts

Tags: java

I want to split a file(suppose a mp3) into four parts.I have tried this code. But only File1.mp3 is working properly. I can't able to play others.What i am doing wrong here?

```
try     {

        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(f);
        long i=f.length();
        long j=i/4;

        FileOutputStream f0=new FileOutputStream("File1.mp3");
        FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream("File2.mp3");
        FileOutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("File3.mp3");
        FileOutputStream f3=new FileOutputStream("File4.mp3");

        for(long k=0;k<j;k++){
            f0.write(in.read());
        }
        f0.close();
        for(long l=0;l<j;l++){
            f1.write(in.read());
        }
        f1.close();
        for(long m=0;m<j;m++){
            f2.write(in.read());  
        }
        f2.close();
        for(long n=0;n<j;n++){
            f3.write(in.read());
        }
        f3.close();

        in.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: What is the variable `w` in the first for loop?

Comment: Sorry i wrote that wrong it's j.

Comment: Beside that you cannot split a file way you are thinking, if the file number turn out to be a prime number or just odd your algorithm will fail.

Comment: Just curious -- why do you need to split up files of various types like this?  This question is kind of unusual.

Comment: @Curtisdf you should ask that question to my teacher!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot split a structured file just like that: [MP3 file has a header at the beginning of the file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure) that describes what's inside the rest of the file. When you split your file, you get a header only in the first part.

As far as cutting non-structured files, say, text, your code should fare much better, as long as you do not mind your sentences split in the middle of a word.

Comment: Frames are 4 bytes long, so you need to read/write them in groups of 4 bytes.

Comment: Is this applicable for JPEG files also?

Comment: @AsifRahman Yes, JPEGs also have structure. You can do better with MP3s than with JPEGs, because they repeat headers every N bytes to remain streamable. JPEGs, on the other hand, were not meant to be streamed, so you'd need to do a lot more work to cut them into pieces that can be used individually.

Comment: Hey, what happened to your fish-splitting analogy?  I thought it worked really nicely.  :-)

Comment: @curtisdf Unfortunately, my fish analogy does not hold all that well with streamable formats, such as MP3 :-(

Answer (score 4):

MP3 files have headers at the beginning or ending, which means you can't just chunk the file based on its size.  You need a library that's able to read those headers and replicate them into each part when you split up the main file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mp3 frames are dependent on each other and cannot just be cut. See [this](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html) format description. Specifically:

> As there is no file header, you can cut any part of MPEG file and play
>   it correctly (this should be done on frame boundaries but most
>   applications will handle incorrect headers). However, for Layer III,
>   this is not 100% correct. Due to internal data organization in MPEG
>   Layer III files, frames are often dependent of each other and they
>   cannot be cut off just like that.

My guess would be that you've managed to split somewhere that is dependent on earlier frames.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html an individual frame of an MP3 file is 32 bits long, which means you need to read/write in groups of bytes. Currently you are writing in groups of 1 byte, which means you are fragmenting the frame (e.g. one byte of the frame is in File1, the other 3 bytes are in file2, messing up whatever program that is reading your mp3 file which is expecting byte1).

However, I would suggest not writing your own mp3 file stream and instead using the built in

`javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream` and `javax.sound.sampled.AudioOutputStream`